# emacs - repeat task max number of times

Tags: emacs, scheduled-tasks, timestamp, org-mode

I need to schedule a task such that it repeats everyday, for a max number of days. If I don't do the task one day, the tasks should accrue, and not simply disappear. For instance, I need to finish a review book before the test; I have calculated I need to do 10 pgs per day until the 28th. All those pages MUST be done by the 28th.

Right now in my agenda org-mode file I have the following for my task:

```
** TODO Read 10pgs of review book
   SCHEDULED: <2012-09-09 Sun .+1d>
```

Is there somehow a way to mix this `.+1d` notation with the timestamp-duration notation:

```
   SCHEDULED: <2012-09-09 Sun>--<2012-09-28 Fri>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's too late for the 28th, but maybe the question remains :

One approach would be not to mark it done everytime you complete it for one day, only to move the scheduled date by one day. Doing this, it is always (and only) scheduled for the day up to which you've done it (e.g. it will show `Sched. 3x:` in the agenda if you're 3 days late).

The easy way is to clone the task, once per each day, and mark them done as you go along (see `C-c C-x c` in [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html#Structure-editing)).